# To show the Full size of image when it was clicked in Gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

Im new to Android and doing some research, I found this [Example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/gridview-loading-photos-from-sd-card.html) on the internet and it's good.

Now, what to I want to do is when an image was clicked, I want to show the full size of the image.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

Either you can get the selected image and launch your activity or dialog to show the image in large size.
 Or you can launch other applications to show the selected image like below :

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("IMAGE_URI")));
```